# How to detect HDMI device is connected with Node JS?

Tags: node.js, electron, hdmi

We required HDMI info in Nodejs and Electron. If any HDMI is connected with system then we have to do some specific task with the Electron application.

Comment: use the webusb api

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try with [`@senzil/cec-monitor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@senzil/cec-monitor) package or simmilar to monitor the HDMI devices.