# Detecting USB and HDMI cable event with node js

Tags: node.js, electron

We have developed a project using electron. We have a requirement to stop our application when someone attached any devices on USB or HDMI port.

Is there any way to detect devices attached in USB or HDMI using node?

I have checked WMIC npm library for node. I am able to get attached devices on USB. But I have failed to get information of attached devices on HDMI port.

Please suggest.

Comment: Isn't he your team mate? ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553635/how-to-detect-hdmi-device-is-connected-with-node-js/54553694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out how we can detect number of screen and any device attached with USB.
Below code might help someone who want to check duplicate screen or USB drive attached to a windows computer:

```
const shell = require('node-powershell');

let ps = new shell({
      executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
      noProfile: true
    });
//To get number of screen attached uncomment the below line
//ps.addCommand('(Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams | where {$_.Active -like "True"}).Active.Count')

//To get attached USB drive with computer
    ps.addCommand('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get caption')
    ps.invoke()
      .then(output => {
        console.log('output '+output);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        ps.dispose();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

HDMI device connection info:
assuming you are connecting / disconnecting a display device, you can use Electron Screen object. (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/screen -> Event: 'display-added').

USB device connection state:
 try https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb-detection

Comment: Hi Sahi, thanks for your reply. We have tried both option to detect activities on USB and HDMI port. But unfortunately, both are not working in our case. However I have figured out the way to detect USB and HDMI activity by Powershell command. I have added my answer below for the solution.